# Django south migration foreign key

Tags: python, mysql, django, migration, django-south

So I have the given model:

```
class FooBar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo,null=True,blank=True)
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar,null=True,blank=True)
    foo_flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    bar_flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

where the logic was that at all times, there can either be a foreign key to `Foo` or `Bar` and not both.But now the logic has changed so that there is always a `Foo` foreign key and sometimes a `Bar`. So my new model looks as such:

```
class FooBar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar,null=True,blank=True)
    bar_flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Now here is the complex part. The `Bar` model looks as such:

```
class Bar(models.Model):
    foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo)
```

so for every previously existing item in the database where the `foo` field is `null` and therefore there is a foreign key to `Bar`, I need the `foo` field to get a foreign key to the same `Foo` object that has the `bar` fields object has a foreign key to. Here is the logic stepped out:

1. delete `FooBar.foo_flag`
2. populate all null `foo` foreign keys with the `Foo` objects from the
   `Bar` foreign keys
3. no longer allow null in `foo` field

**How could I go about writing this migration?**

Answer (score 2):

Best practices for situations like that is make 3 independent migrations:

1. **Data migration**, where you iterate over all **FooBar** items and populate proper values.
2. **Schema migration**, where you set NOT NULL constraint to your ForeignKeys. South will request "default" value for unpopulated items. In most cases you should not have that items, but if something go wrong, you need easily detectable value, so you shoud make *fake* **Foo** item and set it's id as default.
3. **Schema migration**, where you delete **FooBar.foo_flag**

After migration, I recommend check tables for *fake* **Foo** object links and fix data manually if something go wrong.

Comment: in doing what you want, I cannot seem to write the data migration that updates. I posted here if you know how to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439031/django-f-expressions-joined-field