# Django F expressions joined field

Tags: python, sql, django

So I am trying to update my model by running the following:

```
FooBar.objects.filter(something=True).update(foobar=F('foo__bar'))
```

but I get the following error:

```
FieldError: Joined field references are not permitted in this query
```

**if this is not allowed with `F` expressions...how can I achieve this update?**

## ticket

given the information in [this ticket](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14104), I now understand that this is impossible and will never be implemented in django, **but is there any way to achieve this update?** maybe with some work around? I do not want to use a loop because there are over 10 million `FooBar` objects, so SQL is much faster than python.

Answer (score 73):

Django 1.11 adds supports for subqueries. You should be able to do:

```
from django.db.models import Subquery, OuterRef

FooBar.objects.filter(something=True).update(
    foobar=Subquery(FooBar.objects.filter(pk=OuterRef('pk')).values('foo__bar')[:1])
)
```

Comment: This should be set as the accepted answer.
It is very helpful, thank you!

Comment: No, it does not work for me. I got this error:
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1093, "You can't specify target table 'xxx' for update in FROM clause")

Comment: I don't think this works with MySQL, because it performs a query that updates a table based on a subquery that references the same table in the FROM clause.

Answer (score 7):

Why don't use raw sql here:
Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1746125/update-columns-values-with-column-of-another-table-based-on-condition), it will be something like

```
from django.db import connection

raw_query = '''
update app_foobar set app_foobar.foobar = 
(select app_foo.bar from app_foo where app_foo.id = app_foobar.foo_id) 
where app_foobar.something = 1; 
'''

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute(raw_query)
```

Comment: Here's another way to do it: """UPDATE app_foobar b SET mycol = foo.othercol FROM app_foo a WHERE a.id = b.foo_id""".

Answer (score 6):

This is the implementation of Georgi Yanchev's answer for two models:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar)

Foo.objects \
    .filter(foo_field_1=True) \
    .update(foo_field_2=Subquery(
        Bar.objects \
            .filter(id=OuterRef('bar_id')) \
            .values('bar_field_1')[:1]))
```

Comment: `pk=OuterRef('bar')` instead of `id=OuterRef('bar_id')` worked nicely for me, and I prefer it because it only uses model's attributes (`bar`) as opposed to Django's internal ones (`bar_id`).

Answer (score 2):

For anyone wanting a simpler way to do this and not having the case of huge set of objects, below snippet should work just fine:

```
for fooBar in FooBar.objects.filter(something=True):
    fooBar.foobar = fooBar.foo.bar
    fooBar.save(update_fields=['foobar'])
```

For a regular use-cases, this should not present much of a performance difference, especially if being run as part of a data migration.
You can, optionally, also use `select_related` if needed to further optimize.

Answer (score 1):

And there is another way using `bulk_update()` (new in Django 2.2) and optimized for a large number of records:

```
import time
from itertools import islice

batch_size = 2000
objs = FooBar.objects.filter(something=True).annotate(_foobar=F('foo__bar')).iterator(batch_size)
while True:
    ts = time.time()
    batch = list(islice(objs, batch_size))
    if not batch:
        break
    for i in batch:
        i.foobar = i._foobar
    FooBar.objects.bulk_update(batch, ["foobar"])
    print(f"{time.time() - ts:.03f}s [{len(batch)}]")
```