# Bulk update in django with calculations

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-orm

I have 2 models in my project:

```
class Currency(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    value = models.FloatField()

class Good(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    slug = SlugField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    cost_to_display = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    cost_in_currency = models.IntegerField()
    currency = models.ForeignKey(Currency)
```

The idea of such model is to speed up the search by price and have all goods in one currency.
Therefore I need some hook which will update all Goods in case exchange rate was updated.

In raw sql it will looks like this

```
mysql> update core_good set cost_to_display = cost_in_currency * (select core_currency.value from core_currency where core_currency.id = currency_id ) ;
Query OK, 663 rows affected (0.10 sec)
Rows matched: 7847  Changed: 663  Warnings: 0
```

Works pretty fast. Though I tried to implement the same in django admin like this (using [bulk-update](https://github.com/aykut/django-bulk-update)):

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    """Update rate values"""
    goods = Good.objects.all()
    for good in goods:
        good.cost_to_display = good.cost_in_currency * good.currency.value
    bulk_update(goods)
    obj.save()
```

It takes up to 20 minutes to update all records via django admin this way.

What I am doing wrong? What is the right way to update all the prices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is purely untested, but it's sort of work in my mind:

```
from django.db.models import F
Good.objects.all().update(cost_to_display=F('cost_in_currenty') * F('currency__value'))
```

Even you are calling `bulk_update`, you still looped through all goods, which is why your process is slow.

**Edit**:

This won't work because `F()` doesn't support joined fields. It can be done using raw query.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately it doesn't work this way. `F` doesn't allow joined field. It looks like the only solution in this case is raw sql. There is similar case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439031/django-f-expressions-joined-field

Comment: Ah, yea, forgot that. raw sql is the way. I almost have to cry because it looks so close to working.

Comment: It still helped me a lot to get the answer ;) Thx.

Comment: OK. It's not a good answer, but at least what I said about slowness of looping is `True`. :)

Answer (score 1):

For the future readers: any call to `good.currency` in your code is hitting the database. Consider using `select_related` to fetch `Currency` and `Good` objects in one query:

```
goods = Good.objects.select_related('currency')
```

Also now Django comes with `bulk_update` method since version 2.2 [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-update)