# Using subqueries with UPDATE in Django's ORM

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, django-orm

Say I have two models, which I'll call `ModelA` and `ModelB`. Both models have a few fields in common, (represented by `field_one`, `field_two`, and `field_three`). Additionally, `ModelB` has a foreign key to `ModelA`.

```py
class ModelA(Model):
    field_one = models.IntegerField()
    field_two = models.TextField()
    field_three = models.BooleanField()

class ModelB(Model):
    field_one = models.IntegerField()
    field_two = models.TextField()
    field_three = models.BooleanField()
    model_a = models.ForeignKey(ModelA, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

I need to update all instances of `ModelB` to update the field's values to the values of the associated `ModelA` instances. I need to do this operation entirely in the database, without needing to instantiate any model instances (NOT using `.save()` or `bulk_update()`).

I know how I can accomplish this in PostgreSQL using subqueries:

```sql
UPDATE model_b SET (field_one, field_two, field_three) =
    (SELECT field_one, field_two, field_three FROM model_a
     WHERE model_b.model_a_id = model_a.id);
```

**How can I express the above query in Django's ORM?**

---

This is the closest I have been able to get:

```py
ModelB.objects.update(
    field_one=Subquery(ModelA.objects.filter(id=OuterRef('model_a_id')).values(field_one)[:1]),
    field_two=Subquery(ModelA.objects.filter(id=OuterRef('model_a_id')).values(field_two)[:1]),
    field_three=Subquery(ModelA.objects.filter(id=OuterRef('model_a_id')).values(field_three)[:1])
})
```

However, this results in a subquery for every single field:

```sql
UPDATE model_b SET
    field_one = (SELECT model_a.field_one FROM model_a WHERE model_a.id = model_b.model_a_id LIMIT 1),
    field_two = (SELECT model_a.field_two FROM model_a WHERE model_a.id = model_b.model_a_id LIMIT 1),
    field_three = (SELECT model_a.field_three FROM model_a WHERE model_a.id = model_b.model_a_id LIMIT 1);
```

Comment: The first query you have could have been supported by this: `ModelB.objects.update(field_one=F('modela__field_one'), field_two=F('modela__field_two'), field_three=F('modela__field_three'))
`, but unfortunately, django does not support this. See [`here`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439031/django-f-expressions-joined-field) and [`here`](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14104)

Comment: So if you want to do it in one query, subquery is the only option I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the ORM doesn't support annotations spreading multiple columns and I'm not aware of a feature request for it.

If you want to stick to the ORM you'll have to take the possible performance hit (maybe PostgreSQL is smart enough to use only a single one; `EXPLAIN` would tell) otherwise [you'll have to switch to `.raw` SQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/sql/#performing-raw-sql-queries).

Answer (score -2):

by passing modelA as an argument in the modelB class arguments, ModelB and modelC will inherit of every field of modelA

```
class ModelA(Model):
    field_one = models.IntegerField()
    field_two = models.TextField()
    field_three = models.BooleanField()

class ModelB(ModelA):
    pass

class ModelC(ModelA):
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't really relevant to the particular question I am asking. The table structure is non-negotiable here.